# Maxima and minima of sinusoidal function of harmonics

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

I have a function 
$$f(t)=\sin(5t)+\sin(7t)+\sin(9t)+\sin(11t)+\sin(13t).$$
 I need to find the maxima and minima of this function. I know that using first and second derivative test one can find the maxima and minima of a function. I must admit that I have not researched a lot, but I generally use matlab to find the extremum which makes things easier. However I am forced to solve this function analytically.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the cosine addition formula $f(t)\sin(t)$ is a telescopic sum:
$$ f(t)\sin(t) = \frac{\cos(4t)-\cos(14t)}{2}$$
and $f(t)$ is a $2\pi$-periodic, odd function, hence in order to find $\max/\min f$ it is enough to find $\max f$.
Since
$$ f'(t) = \frac{5\cos(3t)-3\cos(5t)-15\cos(13t)+13\cos(15t)}{4\sin^2 t} $$
by using Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind we get that $f(t)$ attains its maximum value when $\cos(t)$ is a root of $105 - 3100 x^2 + 27488 x^4 - 103552 x^6 + 187648 x^8 - 161792 x^{10} + 
 53248 x^{12}$. Numerically
$$ \max f \approx 4.4648, \qquad \min f \approx -4.4648. $$
We may notice this is just a bit tighter than the trivial bound $|f|\leq 5$.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply. Please can you give me a link to Chebyshev polynomial, which is easy to understand?

Comment: @RAN: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials

Comment: thank you for your reply. There was one more requirement which i forgot to mention in the equation. The amplitudes of each of the harmonics is unequal. I have raised another question, would be nice if you could take a look at it. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2956490/maxima-and-minima-of-sinusoidal-harmonics-with-unequal-co-efficients

Comment: Please can you take a look at this question as well...https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3129443/root-of-cosine-function