# Maxima and Minima of sinusoidal harmonics with unequal co-efficients

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima, multinomial-coefficients

This question is related to a similar question I asked before but this time the equation has changed. [Maxima and minima of sinusoidal function of harmonics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2953132/maxima-and-minima-of-sinusoidal-function-of-harmonics)

The equation to which i am trying to find a solution is 
$$f(t)=\ a1\cdot sin(5t)+\ a2\cdot sin(7t)+\ a3\cdot sin(9t)+\ a4\cdot sin(11t)+\ a5\cdot sin(13t).$$

EDIT: I want to find the maxima and minima of the equation mentioned above.
Is it possible to find a solution analytically only, without using computation or numerical methods?

Comment: The answer to your previous question shows that the determination of $\max f$ boils down to the determination of the roots of a high-degree polynomial. Besides the trivial bound $|f(t)|\leq |a_1|+|a_2|+|a_3|+|a_4|+|a_5|$ there is no way to avoid numerical procedures.