# Root of cosine function

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

This question is based on the question I posted before. The link is [Maxima and minima of sinusoidal function of harmonics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2953132/maxima-and-minima-of-sinusoidal-function-of-harmonics)

In need to find the root of following equation
$$\ \omega \cdot \cos(5\omega t)+\ \omega\cdot \cos(7\omega t)+\ \omega\cdot \cos(9 \omega t)+\ \omega\cdot \cos(11 \omega t)+\ \omega\cdot \cos(13 \omega t) = 0$$

In Matlab Chebyshev polynomial function is $ f(x) = ChebyshevT(n,x) $ giving you the $n-$th root. If I substitue $n = 5\cdot \omega,~ 7 \cdot \omega~ $ etc then the Chebyshev polynomial becomes too complicated since $\omega = 2 \cdot \pi \cdot f$.

My way of doing it was replace $\omega \cdot t = \theta$. So the above equation changes to $$\ \frac \theta t \cdot ( \cos(5\theta)+\ \cos(7\theta)+\  \cos(9 \theta)+\cos(11\theta)+ \cos(13 \theta)) = 0$$ and then find the roots of function inside the brackets. Then $\theta $ can be re-substituted to find the value of $t$.

I used Matlab to find the roots using the equation with cosines, and then replacing it with Chebyshev Polynomials of first kind.  However the results are not at all even close. Also i am bit confused about what is to be done with $\frac \theta t$ outside the brackets. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $\omega=0,$ you get $0.$ Otherwise, you can divide the equation by $\omega.$

Comment: Why do you keep this $\omega$ factor everywhere ? Factor it out.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Matlab gave me the equation with $\omega$ everywhere. I was too lazy to fix it in my first equation but i did it in the second

Comment: @user376343: $\omega \neq 0$ which i forgot to put as a condition. If  divide by $\omega$ and replace $\omega \cdot t$ by $\theta$ then what i have left is the stuff inside the brackets. The roots to that equation just dont match.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the equation is the real part of a sum of imaginary exponentials,

$$e^{5i\alpha}(1+e^{2i\alpha}+e^{4i\alpha}+e^{6i\alpha}+e^{8i\alpha})=e^{5i\alpha}\frac{e^{10i\alpha}-1}{e^{2i\alpha}-1}=e^{5i\alpha}\frac{\sin5\alpha e^{5i\alpha}}{\sin\alpha e^{i\alpha}}=\frac{\sin5\alpha}{\sin\alpha} e^{9i\alpha}.$$

The real part cancels when

- $\sin5\alpha$ is zero but $\sin\alpha$ is not, or
- $\cos9\alpha$ is zero.

---

We used

$$e^{i\alpha}-1=\cos\alpha-1+i\sin\alpha=2i\sin\frac\alpha2e^{i\alpha/2}.$$

Comment: Hi, this is a solution, but I would like to use Chebyshev polynomials, since that is what is required, any idea how to solve it using Chebyshev?

Comment: @RAN: no, I am not that masochistic. Who requires that ?

Comment: @RAN: by the way, getting a $13^{th}$ degree polynomial will lead you nowhere.

Comment: how did you end up simplifying the equation? Please can you let me know the steps

Comment: @RAN: the hint is given.